# Many to many complex hibernate mapping

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a DB scenario like this;

**Base tables:**

```
STUDENT (student_id, name)

SPORT (sport_id, name)

SPORT_SUB (sport_sub_id, name)
```

**Many to many mapping tables:**

```
SPORT_CATEGORY (sport_id, sport_sub_id, sport_category_id) 

STUDENT_SPORT_CATEGORY (student_id, sport_category_id)
```

Can anyone suggest a way to map this scenario using hibernate. I generated POJOs and hbm files using Hibernate tools with eclipse and it was successful. But when I tried to insert a Sport and Sport Sub into the db following exception is given:

```
    Foreign key (FK4979B7EDEB6823:student_sport_category [sport_category_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (sport_category [sport_ID,sport_sub_ID])
```

Any suggestion will be highly appreciated. thanks. (fed up with this issue..)

Comment: can you post your hbm files and the code you're using to insert the Sport and Sport Sub?

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't think that you should use hibernate's many-2-many mapping. Instead create a junction tables (sporters or so, with a student_id and an sport_id).
Use than 2 one-to-many relationships.